# Stack and Array List

Tags: java, arrays, stack, user-input

My assignment is to write a test program that prompts a user for 5 strings and displays them in reverse order using MyStack and ArrayList. I need help figuring out how to take user input and put it into the stack and print it in reverse.

[MyStack Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukWgW.png)

[MyMain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnih6.png)

```
My Main:

package arraylist;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author dghelardini
 */
public class ArrayList {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter five names: ");
    }
}


MyStack Class:

package arraylist;

/**
 *
 * @author dghelardini
 */
public class MyStack extends ArrayList
{
  private ArrayList<Object> theList = new ArrayList<>();

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
      return theList.isEmpty();
  }

  public int getSize()
  {
      return theList.size();
  }

  public Object peek()
  {
      return theList.get(getSize()-1);
  }

  public Object pop()
  {
      Object o = theList.get(getSize()-1);
      theList.remove(getSize()-1);
      return o;
  }

  public void push(Object o)
  {
      theList.add(o);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {

      return "stack:" + theList.toString();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Scanner: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html?is-external=true

The user enters the string, then you call the stack to store the 5 strings. Then when you pop, the stack returns the last item that